# Fetch records from core data in sorted order

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, mobile

hi all i new to the iOS programming please help me..... Thanks in advance..

I want to fetch the records from core data in sorted order like this
: suppose i am having 1 field in record with name address and have following entries

Delhi 1, Delhi 10, Delhi 2 A, Delhi 2 B, Delhi Sector 2 A, Delhi Sector 1, Delhi Sector 10, Delhi Sector 2 B

I want result in the following order

Delhi 1
Delhi 2 A
Delhi 2 B
Delhi 10
Delhi Sector 1
Delhi Sector 2 A
Delhi Sector 2 B
Delhi Sector 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the sorting using NSSortDescriptor by using the following code.

// Set the sort descriptor for a particular key.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"address" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

now set this descriptor to your fetch request.

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: using sort descriptor i am getting in following order Delhi 1, Delhi 10, Delhi 2....But i want Delhi 1 Delhi 2, Delhi 10

Comment: @rocky171 I had updated my answer's code, check it out. now it should fulfil your requirements.

Comment: i am getting following crash--unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)

Comment: @rocky171 the last thing that you can try bro is NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"address" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]; it should work.